# Need help making a slime farm

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I made a mine that led into a cave. The cave is in a slime chunk so as you expect slimes spawn there big and small. They gave a great source of slime balls that I could use for sticky pistons. So that made me thinking... how about a slime farm, but how the heck do I do that. I know slimes don't have a pathfinding ability so they would just jump into ravines when they try to attack you and I know they drown after spending 15 seconds in water but how do I make the actual farm mechanics. What I want is after the farm kills the slimes and the slimeballs are carried by water into a soul sand/ magma block propelled water current that sends it to the world surface. There a hopper collects the slimeballs and puts it in a chest. Unless there's a better way to do it. So basically my question is: **How do I make the slime farm functional and fully automatic?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cool thing with slimes is that when on water (either full block or not), they do not jump at all. So the good thing is make a flowing water system in that specific chunk to move the slime somewhere where you can kill them with some redstone machinery or by hand.

To try and speed up the farm, make another base you can live in there to continue spawning slimes to continue the farm a bit more while doing some other business.

Comment: Would a suffacation chamber work for slimes?

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow Well, you can try to suffocate them, but remember, the smaller ones are 1 block height. So maybe you can do that, but there are other ways of making the farm.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are afk, a system where a slime has to lock onto you won’t work. I’ve seen slime farm designs where you simply let them jump into a pit themselves, but you could also have a water system that pushes them into a pit. The hard part would be killing them and allowing their drops to float to the surface... maybe you could rig up some sort of water trap or simply make the water corridor to your elevator contained so they drown. Hope this helps!